# Pandas merge two dataframe and drop extra rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can  I merge/join these two dataframes ONLY on "sample_id" and drop the extra rows from the second dataframe when merging/joining?

Using **pandas** in Python.

First dataframe (fdf)

```
| sample_id | name  |
|-----------|-------|
| 1         | Mark  |
| 1         | Dart  |
| 2         | Julia |
| 2         | Oolia |
| 2         | Talia |
```

Second dataframe (sdf)

```
| sample_id | salary | time |
|-----------|--------|------|
| 1         | 20     | 0    |
| 1         | 30     | 5    |
| 1         | 40     | 10   |
| 1         | 50     | 15   |
| 2         | 33     | 0    |
| 2         | 23     | 5    |
| 2         | 24     | 10   |
| 2         | 28     | 15   |
| 2         | 29     | 20   |
```

So the resulting df will be like -

```
| sample_id | name  | salary | time |
|-----------|-------|--------|------|
| 1         | Mark  | 20     | 0    |
| 1         | Dart  | 30     | 5    |
| 2         | Julia | 33     | 0    |
| 2         | Oolia | 23     | 5    |
| 2         | Talia | 24     | 10   |
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this as well, should be a simple matter of an inner or a left join, but for some reason pandas always keeps the larger dataframe regardless of method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are duplicates, so need helper column for correct [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter:

```
df = (fdf.assign(g=fdf.groupby('sample_id').cumcount())
        .merge(sdf.assign(g=sdf.groupby('sample_id').cumcount()), on=['sample_id', 'g'])
        .drop('g', axis=1))
print (df)
   sample_id   name  salary  time
0          1   Mark      20     0
1          1   Dart      30     5
2          2  Julia      33     0
3          2  Oolia      23     5
4          2  Talia      24    10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final_res = pd.merge(df,df2,on=['sample_id'],how='left')
final_res.sort_values(['sample_id','name','time'],ascending=[True,True,True],inplace=True)

final_res.drop_duplicates(subset=['sample_id','name'],keep='first',inplace=True)
```